# SQL exception: ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: java, oracle11g

st.executeQuery("insert into users_website values('"+user+"','"+password+"')");

I am trying to execute the above code and getting exception;
I have trigger defined for my table with sequence using oracle 11g

```
create or replace TRIGGER users_website_t1 
before INSERT ON users_website 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT users_website_insert.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id 
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

​

Comment: users_website has 3 fields, and you are only providing 2 in the insert. Either provide 3 fields, or name the 2 you are passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
Insert into users_website(user,password) values('"+user+"','"+password+"')

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possibilities for this error :

1) This error can occur when you are performing an INSERT and the values entered are less in number than the columns that you are inserting into.

2) This error can also occur when you perform a sub-select in a WHERE clause or HAVING clause but the sub-select returns too few columns.

Can you try to check values before it is added into users_website table whether you have both the values or not.